# How can I edit a WP custom template file with a custom table?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Creating a custom template file in WP which does the same as the standard template file is rather simple, but when I try to add an html table inside the customer template, then the table doesn't align with the rest of the theme (I use theme twentytwentyone as a test) and the table goes completely on the left side of the screen.

The code I started from, is the standard template for theme twentytwentyone:

```
<?php
//  the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-page' );
// my added table
?>
<table><th></th><th></th></table>
<?php
// end added table
    // If comments are open or there is at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Maybe I should start from another template but i don't know which one.
I cannot use the block editor in WP or a plugin to build up my table, because in the table there will be data from a custom mySQL table.

Or if you have better ideas on how to implement the above, I am happy to listen to what you have in mind.
Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: You need to add the content in content-page.php template or load another one 
different/new template after content-page.php . Or if you just want to be there change it to echo '<table><th></th><th></th></table>'; which will be hard to manage later on. I will suggest loading second template for example content-table.php.

Answer (score 1):

Each solution depends on what you need.

Solution 1

```
<?php
//  the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-page' );
// my added table
//This is hard to manage if we work with alot of data or loops etc.
echo '<table><th></th><th></th></table>';

// end added table
    // If comments are open or there is at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Solution 2

Open file content-page.php located in yourtheme/template-parts/content and add your table there

```
<?php
//  the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-page' );

// end added table
    // If comments are open or there is at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Solution 3

Create new template in yourtheme/template-parts/content for example content-table.php and load it

```
<?php
//  the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-page' );
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-table' );

// end added table
    // If comments are open or there is at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin that's exactly what I was looking for. I can go on now.